# Get the " listen EINVAL" when starting up Node.js server, Why?

Tags: node.js

After I upgrade to Node 0.6.18, I got the error:  listen EINVAL when start.

It seems not it cannot find the file I'm running.

e.g. i run   node myserver.js

and then it says myserver.js throw EINVAL  which seems to be a file not found error.

however, I'm not sure.  What is that?

Comment: What's your code look like dood? I'd throw the contents of myserver.js into an https://gist.github.com if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `listen(3p)` man page:

> ```
>   EINVAL The socket is already connected.
> ```

Make sure something isn't already listening on that port.

Comment: Thanks.   It has a ghost process running the same port which I don't know. Thanks.  HMmm that message should be more detail.